# libcurl - как парсить HTTP заголовок?

Tags: c++, http, curl, парсер, веб-сервер

Учусь писать HTTP веб-сервер. Сам сервер есть. Запускаю сервак, посылаю HTTP-запрос `curl -D dumpbin 127.0.0.1:2000`. На сервере сохраняю запрос в строковую переменную. Теперь (и я не знаю, как это сделать) мне надо распарсить весь полученный запрос, составить ответ и отправить обратно. С отправкой я справлюсь, а вот с парсингом и с составлением ответа возникли проблемы. 
Сказали, что следует использовать libcurl, но я не понимаю, как им можно парсить готовые строки и можно ли.
Помогите, пожалуйста, примером такого использования этой либы, если он возможен.
Посоветуйте, какие можно использовать библиотеки еще, чтобы решить эту задачу.

```
//Вид запроса (это то, что вернул мой эхо-сервер при использовании утилиты curl): 

    request = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n"
              "Host: 127.0.0.1:5991\r\n"
              "User-Agent: curl/7.47.0\r\n"
              "Accept: */*\r\n"
              "\r\n";

    //Вид ответа (это я прочитал в комментах к заданию на степике):
    answer = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
             "Content-length: %d\r\n"
             "Connection: close\r\n"
             "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
             "\r\n"
             "%s";
```

Суть в том, что есть данные, которые разделены `\r\n` и заканчиваются двойным переводом каретки и строки `\r\n\r\n`

Comment: Покажите пример самого HTTP заголовка, или это заголовки? Как я помню http заголовки это "text: test разделенный 10 байтом" Если это они то их можно очень простенько распарсить через while, for.

Comment: Добавил в описание вид запроса.

Comment: @LigvestO, в чём конкретно ваша проблема? Не знаете как найти в строке `\r` или `\n`? Попробуйте почитать man по strchr, strtok, strstr etc (хотя это и не C++ вовсе).

Comment: Проблемы нету, но гораздо эффективнее было бы нового велосипеда не изобретать, а использовать уже отлаженную и сформированную библиотеку. В итоге велосипед писать пришлось.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***tl;dr*** см. конец ответа для реализации парсера заголовков

---

`licurl` используют, как правило, для написания клиентов, смотрите [FAQ](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Can_I_write_a_server_with_libcur):

> 5.17 Can I write a server with libcurl?
>
> No. libcurl offers no functions or building blocks to build any kind
>   of internet protocol server. libcurl is only a client-side library.
>   For server libraries, you need to continue your search elsewhere but
>   there exist many good open source ones out there for most protocols
>   you could possibly want a server for. And there are really good
>   stand-alone ones that have been tested and proven for many years.
>   There's no need for you to reinvent them!

В вольном переводе:

> 5.17 Могу ли я использовать libcurl для написания сервера?
>
> Нет. libcurl не предлагает функций или других строительных блоков для
>   создания какого либо IP сервера. libcurl это только клиентская
>   библиотека. Вам нужно продолжить ваши поиски библиотеки для построения
>   сервера. Существует большое количество таких библиотек с открытым
>   исходным кодом для большинства протоколов. Также существует большое
>   кол-во проверенных годами stand-alone приложений. Вам не стоит
>   изобретать их заново.

Хотя для построения клиента `libcurl` действительно очень удобная вещь, как упомянул в своем ответе @Pink Tux. В том числе заголовки вы получаете уже разбитые по одному.

---

Для построения сервера, как один из вариантов, можно использовать [mongoose](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose) (на `c`, в виде пары `.c/.h`, добавляемой к вашему проекту, либо одну из многочисленных `c++` оберток). Пример минимального сервера достаточно громоздкий, поэтому приводить здесь не буду. Можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/master/examples/simplest_web_server/simplest_web_server.c).

---

Еще один вариант - библиотека [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/) которая изначально планировалась как часть `boost` (но потом планы разработчиков поменялись). В простейшем виде http сервер выглядит так:

```
namespace http = boost::network::http;

struct handler;
typedef http::server<handler> http_server;

struct handler {
    void operator() (http_server::request const &request,
                     http_server::response &response) {
        response = http_server::response::stock_reply(
            http_server::response::ok, "Hello, world!");
    }

    void log(http_server::string_type const &info) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << info << '\n';
    }
};

int main(int arg, char * argv[]) {
    handler handler_;
    http_server::options options(handler_);
    http_server server_(
        options.address("0.0.0.0")
               .port("8000"));
    server_.run();
}
```

---

Если вам нужно что-то еще более высокоуровневое (с поддержкой шаблонов, json, middlewares), можно взять [crow](https://github.com/ipkn/crow), которая подключается к вашему проекту одним заголовочным файлом. По духу это напоминает [Python Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). Пример сервера:

```
#include "crow_all.h"

int main()
{
    crow::SimpleApp app;

    CROW_ROUTE(app, "/")([](){
        return "Hello world";
    });

    app.port(18080).multithreaded().run();
}
```

---

Если все-таки интересно самому разобрать заголовки, то можно например таким кодом:

```
std::istringstream rawstream(raw);
std::map<std::string, std::string> headers;
std::string header;
while (std::getline(rawstream, header) && header != "\r") {
    std::string::size_type index = header.find(':');
    if (index != std::string::npos) {
        headers.insert(std::make_pair(
            boost::algorithm::trim_copy(header.substr(0, index)), 
            boost::algorithm::trim_copy(header.substr(index + 1))
        ));
    }
}
```

В `raw` типа `std::string` помещаете строку с вашими заголовками (либо даже целиком запрос клиента), в `headers` получаете `map` из имен/значений заголовков. Используете к примеру так:

```
std::cout << headers["Content-Type"] << std::endl;
```

Обратите внимание, что по стандарту имя заголовка может иметь любой регистр. Поэтому `CONTENT-TYPE`, `content-type` и `Content-Type` это все один заголовок, и для удобства можно перед добавлением в `map` привести имя заголовка в нижний регистр:

```
headers.insert(std::make_pair(
    boost::algorithm::to_lower_copy(boost::algorithm::trim_copy(header.substr(0, index))),
    boost::algorithm::trim_copy(header.substr(index + 1))
));
```

Действующий пример на [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/INUYAt).

---

P.S. Для тестирования вместо `curl` можно использовать [postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) в котором можно задавать заголовки, тело страниц (в том числе json), сохранять наборы запросов и т.д.

Comment: Решения не нашел во всех библиотеках, предложенных (+ некоторые, найденные в течении "расследования"), но использовал предложенный код. Подстроил его под себя. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

libcurl предоставляет возможность задавать обработчик для разных данных. Например, чтобы "поймать" заголовки ответа, можно воспользоваться следующим подходом:

```
static size_t header_callback(char *buffer, size_t size,
                          size_t nitems, void *userdata)
{
  /*
   * Эта функция будет вызываться на каждый возвращаемый заголовок.
   */
  return nitems * size;
}

int main()
{
  CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://yahoo.com/");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, header_callback);
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Подробней - см. в [документации по libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/). Кроме того, для C++ есть обёртки, например, [curlcpp](https://github.com/JosephP91/curlcpp).

Comment: Видел. Пробовал. Как работает - не понимаю. Мне нужно на сервере обрабатывать запрос. А это, как я понял, клиентская функция, чтобы обработать уже ответ от сервера.